Role switch github+AWS+terraform null_resource
In landingzone environment i have multiple OU. I have github action workflow and it is authenticated using OIDC. There is no issue with authentication between AWS and github. I also have terraform to deploy resources. I have one requirement to delete default vpc from each member accounts from the landing zone.
Terraform
resource "null_resource" "assume_role" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
      set -e
      ROLE_ARN="arn:aws:iam::12345678:role/OrganizationAccountAccessRole"
      eval $(aws sts assume-role --role-arn $ROLE_ARN --role-session-name delete_vpc_session | jq -r '.Credentials | "export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=\(.AccessKeyId)\nexport AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=\(.SecretAccessKey)\nexport AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=\(.SessionToken)\n"')
      chmod +x delete_default_vpc.sh
      ./delete_default_vpc.sh
    EOT
    environment = {
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID     = var.aws_access_key_id
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = var.aws_secret_access_key
      AWS_SESSION_TOKEN     = var.aws_session_token
    }
  }
}

GihubAction workflow
name: Delete Default VPC

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  delete-default-vpc:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    permissions:
      id-token: write
      contents: read

    steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Configure AWS credentials using OIDC
      id: aws-credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v3
      with:
        role-to-assume: ${{ secrets.AWS_PIPELINE_ROLE_ARN_ABC }}
        role-session-name: aws_oidc
        aws-region: us-east-1
        
    - name: oide test
      uses: actions/github-script@v6
      id: script
      timeout-minutes: 10
      with:
        debug: true
        script: |
          const token = process.env['ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN']
          const runtimeUrl = process.env['ACTIONS_ID_TOKEN_REQUEST_URL']
          core.setOutput('TOKEN', token.trim())
          core.setOutput('IDTOKENURL', runtimeUrl.trim())

    - name: oidc run
      run: |
         IDTOKEN=$(curl -H "Authorization: bearer ${{ steps.script.outputs.TOKEN }}" ${{ steps.script.outputs.IDTOKENURL }} -H "Accept: application/json; api-version=2.0" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{}" | jq -r '.value')
         echo $IDTOKEN
         jwtd() {
           if [[ -x $(command -v jq) ]]; then
             jq -R 'split(".") | .[0],.[1] | @base64d | fromjson' <<< "${1}"
             echo "Signature: $(echo "${1}" | awk -F'.' '{print $3}')"
           fi
         }
         jwtd $IDTOKEN
         echo "idToken=${IDTOKEN}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
      id: tokenid

    - name: Set AWS environment variables
      run: |
        echo "TF_VAR_aws_access_key_id=${{ steps.aws-credentials.outputs.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        echo "TF_VAR_aws_secret_access_key=${{ steps.aws-credentials.outputs.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        echo "TF_VAR_aws_session_token=${{ steps.aws-credentials.outputs.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV

    - name: Terraform Init
      run: terraform init

    - name: Terraform Plan
      run: terraform plan

    - name: Terraform Apply
      run: terraform apply --auto-approve

The error i am getting
terraform apply --auto-approve
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: us-east-1
    AWS_REGION: us-east-1
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ***
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ***
    AWS_SESSION_TOKEN: ***
    TF_VAR_aws_access_key_id: 
    TF_VAR_aws_secret_access_key: 
    TF_VAR_aws_session_token: 

Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution
plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # null_resource.assume_role will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "assume_role" {
      + id = (known after apply)
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
null_resource.assume_role: Creating...
null_resource.assume_role: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
null_resource.assume_role (local-exec): Executing: ["/bin/sh" "-c" "      set -e\n      ROLE_ARN=\"arn:aws:iam::12345678:role/OrganizationAccountAccessRole\"\n      eval $(aws sts assume-role --role-arn $ROLE_ARN --role-session-name delete_vpc_session | jq -r '.Credentials | \"export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=\\(.AccessKeyId)\\nexport AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=\\(.SecretAccessKey)\\nexport AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=\\(.SessionToken)\\n\"')\n      chmod +x delete_default_vpc.sh\n      ./delete_default_vpc.sh\n"]

null_resource.assume_role (local-exec): Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".

null_resource.assume_role (local-exec): Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".
null_resource.assume_role: Creation complete after 2s 

Apply complete! Resources: 1 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed

This is the role "OrganizationAccountAccessRole" I want to use because this role is available in all member accounts. AWS_PIPELINE_ROLE_ARN_ABC role is used to communicate with AWS.
I tried to use below inside terraform null_resources
eval $(aws sts assume-role --role-arn $ROLE_ARN --role-session-name delete_vpc_session | jq -r '.Credentials | "export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=\(.AccessKeyId)\nexport AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=\(.SecretAccessKey)\nexport AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=\(.SessionToken)\n"')

But I was getting error. Expected result would to use OrganizationAccountAccessRole to delete vpc from all member account in AWS landingzone

If you take a look at the env output from GHA, you'll see that the TF_VAR_aws_* are empty. That's probably because you are not referencing the outputs of the aws-credentials correctly. Those should be steps.aws-credentials.outputs.aws-access-key-id, steps.aws-credentials.outputs.aws-secret-access-key, and steps.aws-credentials.outputs.aws-session-token. But that's probably only the first step in debugging.

It works now, what i did actually, I added sts policy on this role  AWS_PIPELINE_ROLE_ARN_ABC. But i still have question if there is possibility to assume web identity in the null_resource
